# scrambled uart output

Tags: pic, uart, rs232, mplab, xc8

I am new to pic uart communicatioon with PC using RS232.
I have tried the below code and used Hyperterminal to view the output.
But the output gets scrambled here and there each time when I reset pic. I have tried changing stopbits from 1 to 0 in the hyperterminal but the output remains the same.
The settings kept on hyperterminal is

1. Baudrate 9600
2. Parity none
3. Stopbits 1 & 2(for both the output remains the same.)
4. No. Of bits 8

Am using PIC16F877a and have coded using MPLAB XC8 compiler
The outputs are there in the attachment

Could you please tell where i did the mistake.

```
void main()

{
TRISC = 0x80;
TXSTA=0x24;     
RCSTA=0x90;           
SPBRG=0x81;           
unsigned int i=0;
char name[]="Sample Output";

while(name[i]!='\0')
{
  TXREG=name[i];
  while(!TXIF);
  __delay_ms(1000);
  i++;

}
while(1);
}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you come up with `0x81` for `SPBRG`? How is your micro clocked?

Comment: How is the PIC wired to the PC? What cable and connector is used?

Comment: @Vladimir Cravero ..Am using 20Mhz on board crystal oscillator for clocking. And I choosed 0x81 by the formula SPBRG = (FOSC-(baud rate*16))/(9600*16)

Comment: @Entrepreneur I have used a DB9 connector which is then connected to a RS232-to-USB converter cable

Comment: Definitely don't want to guess stop bits, it could throw you out of sink

Comment: "I have used a DB9 connector which is then connected to a RS232-to-USB converter cable" - RS232 is +-12V, the PIC is 0-5V TTL. How did you interface them?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott used MAX232 to interface

Comment: I tried your code on a 16F873 with TTL-USB converter. Apart from an occasional extra character during reset (expected since TXD is floating at that point) it worked perfectly.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Thanks alot man. I finally figured it out, there is some problem with the cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to poll the Transmit Shift Register Status TRMT rather than TXIF. When TRMT==1 the register is empty and it is ready to transmit a byte.

But upon a second look I notice that the wrong characters are always off by the same bit in the ASCII code. When a character is wrong the first (low order) bit in the ASCII character is supposed to be 1, but it is replaced with a 0. 'S' turns into 'R', 'O' into 'N', 'u' into 't'. That seems like a signal integrity issue over the data cable.

While I do think that you will need to poll the TRMT bit, I don't think that your current problem is software. Look for anything that may affect the quality of the cable connection.

Comment: But while doing the loop back test, the results are positive. If anything was wrong with the cable then i should have known at that time right? By the way I did replace TXIF with TRMT. :)

Comment: thanks to you. Finally figured it out that the problem was with the cable. And the error was also seen during the loop back test when i gave repeated 'A' as input. :)